# Why is venv launcher not working properly to create a virtual environment?

Tags: python, command-line, python-venv

I am trying to make a virtual environment with VENV but I keep getting the below error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>python3 -m venv MyPythonEnv/
Unable to copy 'c:\\users\\k1921013\\appdata\\local\\activestate\\cache\\4cf0023a\\venvlauncher.exe'
Unable to copy 'c:\\users\\k1921013\\appdata\\local\\activestate\\cache\\4cf0023a\\venvwlauncher.exe'
Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

any ideas about what is wrong here? I have seen a post suggesting it is the order of python on my system variable but that doesn't seem to be the case and the error messages on mine look like it's an issue with Venvlauncher?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: ever found an answer to this?